# Prove $\{x \in X : f(x)=g(x)+ 2 \} \in \Sigma $

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma )$ be a measurable space and $f,g: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be measurable functions. Prove that $\{x \in X : f(x)=g(x)+ 2 \} \in \Sigma $. You may use the algebra of measurable functions.

---

Not sure how to do this. If $g$ is measurable then $\{x:g(x)>a\} \in \Sigma$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$. Then does that mean since $g(x)+2>a+2>a$ for all $a$, we have $\{x:g(x)+2>a\} \in \Sigma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $[h \sim c]$ denotes the set $\{x\mid h(x) \sim c\}$ (where $\sim$ is any relation), notice that your set is:

$$[f - g = 2] = [f - g \le 2] \cap [f - g \ge 2]$$

both of which are measurable since $f - g$ is measurable.